# How to load ccTLDs domains for users of different countries

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

If i am going to google.com then it will open the website https://www.google.co.in/ if i'm opening it from India but if I am gooing to google.com from another country lets say UK then it will automatically redirect to https://www.google.co.uk/. I want to do similar set up for my website . And I think that it has something to do withe the .htaccess file . Correct me if i'm wrong and suggest me the ways how to achieve this in php or wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in htaccess as the only location based information you can get is the ip address.
I would recommend PHP because the IP address database changes frequently.

Lookup something called GeoIP